# ModemManager behavior on SIM card switch

Tags: embedded-linux, gsm

Hey I am building an embedded linux device using Yocto, that will transmit some data via GSM network. It will work in a rough conditions, poor GSM range, so it will switch SIM cards often to find the best network.

My question is - does the modem manager rewrites the current APN during each sim card switch? Or does it use already saved?

I am asking this, beacause I witnessed GSM modems' flash being killed after like 3 months, because of APN being rewrited on each network switch.

Thanks!